# Observe a BOOL change in another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean, observers

In `vc1` im setting a `BOOL` `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"myKey"];`

In `vc2` I want to observe if this `BOOl` changes `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"myKey"]`

Checked here
[Add Observer to BOOL variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624021/add-observer-to-bool-variable)
and
[Registering a bool for a NSNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226036/registering-a-bool-for-a-nsnotification)

neither seemed to fit my pattern

Comment: It's you who controls when and where that BOOL gets set. Why not fire a notification whenever you do it?

Comment: No it doesn't in my case, the BOOl gets changed through another class

Comment: And you are in control of what that class does.

Comment: Yes but not When it changes/does it

Comment: Well… how does it change in that class?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code it will call when your `BOOL` value changed.You can use **KVO** to observe the value of your `myKey` .Write this in any class where you observe the values.Write it in `viewDidLoad` in `vc2`

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"myKey"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];
```

Implement this method in your class where you have added observer in `vc2`

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
{

    //check here if it is myKey than do something
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myKey"]){
        //do your work
    NSLog(@"KVO: %@ changed property %@ to value %@", object, keyPath, change);
    BOOL newValue = [[change objectForKey: NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] boolValue];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not my key");
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];

    }
}
```

Remove observer in `vc2` `dealloc`

```
-(void)dealloc{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myKey"];
}
```

In `observeValueForKeyPath` check for if value changed for `myKey` than do whatever you want to.

Comment: This is blatantly incorrect. You don't set properties on `NSUserDefaults`. Please don't run after rep.

Comment: @duci9y why this is incorrect have you used it??I have used it and wotking perfect???

Comment: observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context should call super if the key isn't one you're interested in

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is not KVO compliant. That it works for you is merely by chance, the functionality might break in a future update and you'd be none the wiser.

Comment: @duci9y You are wrong than it is fully KVO complaint and you can observe the value.

Answer (score 0):

Register for the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` and check your user defaults whenever the notification fires to see if the value that changed is the one you're interested in.

Comment: You can not get which keyname changed with this

Comment: "This notification does not contain a userInfo dictionary." Even worse, the only specification of when NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification is posted says that it is posted "when a persistent domain is changed"

Comment: it will notify you when not value changed when it writes to the specific persistent domain and second you can not able to find which key you have changed i think this should require as there are so many keys in user defaults and it may have different values.You will not get this information from `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification`

Comment: @codester Who said it only fires when changed are persisted to disk?

Comment: not persisted but change in `persitent domain` docs:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @codester So? I cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: Problem is you when you set `key1` to YES and `Key2` to NO you will not get to know which key is changed and to what value.This notification only notifies anything in NSUserDefaults has changed but you will not get what has chaged.